# Переадресация всех запросов с не существующих поддоменов на главную

Tags: apache, dns, домен

Что необходимо сделать чтобы все запросы,которые идут на не существующие поддомены,отправлялись на главную основы?(что-то слышал про вариант 404,но он не подходит).

*Сейчас при попытке достучаться до не существующего саба получаю ошибку от браузера,якобы сервер не доступен.*

Пробовал указывать что-то подобное,история повторяется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне недавно на ухо шепнули,что нужно еще как-то правильно сконфигурировать `.htaccess`...

Comment: Используете VirtualServer в конфигурации Apache?

Comment: @Daniel Shatz Использую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить в DNS вот такую запись думаю будет достаточно:

```
*.mywebsite.ru CNAME mywebsite.ru
```

*От автора вопроса:* важно учитывать что проблема не решится только при указании данного в `ДНС` домена.Здесь нужно сконфигурировать правильно конфигурационные файлы `NGINX\APACHE` (если у вас все вместе и NGINX как прокси-сервер,то править скорее всего нужно только его).

Comment: Странно,не работает вариант.Обновил старт-пост

Comment: to Maksym, а пингом проверяли? Возможно записи завернулись на нужный IP, и осталось на сервере подтянуть...